# Websockets on Tomcat: how to shutdown the server cleanly?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

How can I intercept the shut down event of an endpoint running on the server (like the destroy methods of the servlets, so to say) for logging or other purposes ?

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

Spring 4 Java Config:

Implement SmartLifecycle (when using Java based configuration, or translate the Java code to XML):

```
@Configuration
public class CycleBean implements SmartLifecycle {

    public CycleBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //when stopped call 
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable arg0) {
        //
    }
}
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html paragraph 4.6 Customizing the nature of a bean, like:

```
<bean id="lifecycleProcessor" class="org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor">
  <!-- timeout value in milliseconds -->
  <property name="timeoutPerShutdownPhase" value="10000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. However my context doesn't have a spring framework, just an EndPoint running in a Tomcat webapp.

Comment: My bad, I've never heard of `EndPoint` so didn't regard it as an environment

Comment: BTW, I misspelled it: I should have written `Endpoint`  [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html)

Comment: But... I'd say override the `onClose(Session session, EndpointConfig config)` method. First (if possible) call the `super.onClose(session, closeReason)`, then call the method for logging

Comment: Thank you Danielson. However, the method `onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason)` is triggered for each session that closes, not when the endpoint instance shuts down. And I can't find a method `onClose(Session session, EndpointConfig config)` to override... Which class should it belong to?